# Restoring notes from .bak file

Tags: backup, restore, lg, notes

I had LG G4 which i've backed-up and kept the `.bak` file on my computer . I sold the phone but I want to restore the notes from the QuickMemo+ app. Tried to find applications for my mac that would help with this but all of them require connecting a phone to restore the data. Any ideas how can I achieve this without using actual phone? (that is, using computer only).

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to open the file(s) with a text or hex editor just to see if you can see and text (fragments)?

Comment: Do you mean poening the .bak file with text editor? That does not work.. the file doesn't open

Comment: Then you are using the wrong program. As long as the file is not too large a text editor can open any file, independently if it contains text or not. At least a hex editor should be able to open any file.

Comment: first thanks, ill try to use another text editor, but how can I find there the notes? the backup file is 3GB and contains all my phone data, and I cannot remember something specific to ctrl+f.

Comment: @alecxs I used wondershare mobile trans

Comment: according to [FAQ](https://mobiletrans.wondershare.com/faq) that is a zip file. open file with 7-zip and tell us what's inside. look for files and/or folders with name *com.lge.qmemoplus* or *(user)data.img*

Comment: Hi, @alecxs finally found 7zip for mac that accepts that file, it requires password although i don't think i set one when backing up. tried many passwords i use but that didn't work. Anything to do with that? or the information is lost unless i find the password?

Comment: there are bruteforce password crackers for zip, but i cannot recommend one. check the wondershare program folder for config files maybe there is some random password in plain text in one of the files